# Build FFMPEG with --enable-libxcb in Linux

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use the x11grab command from FFMPEG. So to install FFMPEG I did

`opkg install ffmpeg`

However, I then noticed that to use the x11grab command I needed to build it with --enable-libxcb which when I run . How do I do this? Do I need to install any other depenencies to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--enable-libxcb` dependencies are autodetected, so you never need to explicitly list this option unless you are manually disabling autodetection and other components.

There are four libxcd configuration options:

```
--enable-libxcb          enable X11 grabbing using XCB [autodetect]
--enable-libxcb-shm      enable X11 grabbing shm communication [autodetect]
--enable-libxcb-xfixes   enable X11 grabbing mouse rendering [autodetect]
--enable-libxcb-shape    enable X11 grabbing shape rendering [autodetect]
```

According to the `configure` file the dependencies for each are:

- libxcb: `xcb/xcb.h`, version 1.4 or above.
- libxcb-shm: `xcb/shm.h`
- libxcb-xfixes: `xcb/xfixes.h`
- libxcb-shape: `xcb/shape.h`

You need to install whatever package supplies these. I'm not sure what distro you are using so you'll have to look it up. Or you may need to compile libxcb yourself.